# Laravel 5.3 Homestead php7 reload php.ini file

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

[image]I made some changes to /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini on my laravel homestead machine.  But I can't get it to load the new settings.  Tried restarting nginx, restart php7, etc...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The file  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini is for PHP-running trough commandline.

There should a php.ini in /etc/php/7.0/fpm with the settings for PHP-FPM. After you've edited that, restart php-fpm with this command

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Comment: I found that php.ini file and edited it, but got this -  Failed to restart php7-fpm.service: Unit php7-fpm.service not found.

Comment: I added phpinfo() images @Mauran Muthiah

Comment: try service php7.0-fpm restart instead

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks @Mauran Muthiah - Would upvote you but reached limit for day.  I will later tho...  Thanks again.   :)

Comment: @cmac no problem!

Comment: In my case, I had to run `service php7.3-fpm restart` and provide `vagrant` as the password.

Comment: If you type `service php` and then press tab it will list the various versions you have installed.

Answer (score 7):

I'm also running Homestead but a more recent version, for me it was the following:

```
service php7.1-fpm restart
```